# responsive mobile design viewport

Tags: mobile, viewport

I am trying to get a mobile site to behave. I am using the `viewport` meta tag to make the site fit all screens and be scalable. I have made all table and all images (over 200 px wide)  100% width, have set the `viewport` tag to:

```
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, user-scalable=yes"
```

because I want it to be able to zoom in for those needing to read the text, yet have it open initially to fitting centered on the screen (any screen).

It *almost* fits on `iphones` and androids in portrait (testing on `iphone` 4 & 5 as well as galaxy iii android). But part of it is still not visible on the right? It fits fine on ipads or in landscape mode on phones. This is driving me insane, and must be something simple I am over looking. Live view is: `password-reset.com/mobileusers/`

I am using `jquery colorbox` on the page - could that be interfering? I thought `colorbox` was responsive?

Any help or suggestions will be gratefully accepted - what do I need to post of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your table that holds the `More Info`, `Purchase` and `Testimonials` has a `width="340"` on it.  That is what is messing everything up.